# JRuby: How to cast an object stored in blob column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I have an java object that is stored in a MySQL database (blob column).
How can i use or cast this object?

In the database i do have someting like this

```
Tab:
+------------+---------+
|    ID      |  CONTENT|
+------------+---------+
| 1          | (BLOB)  |
| 2          | (BLOB)  |
+------------+---------+
```

In CONTENT column a java object is installed, let says *MyJavaObject Class*.
If i try to read the content within jruby, i got a string object back.

```
require 'java'
$CLASSPATH << "my/java/class/folder"
java_import 'MyJavaObject'
```

In JRuby i could create a new MyJavaObject.

```
testObject = MyJavaObject.new
testObject.doSomeThing
```

But if read the content column:

```
 obj = Tab.CONTENT
 puts obj.class

=>nilClass
```

How can i tell JRuby to handel the object to be a java class?

Comment: cast? do you mean de-serialize?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! May I refer you to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Show your object, your code, your tabel structure.